# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cec' when running as a linux service

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a python script after the start-up of a raspberry pi:

```
import cec
import sys
import time
import configparser
from tuya.devices import TuyaSmartSwitch
...
```

If I run the command manually `/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/pi/subwoofer_switch/subwoofer_control.py` it works fine and has no issues.

But if I put this in a service script `sudo systemctl --force --full edit subwoofer.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My script to control suboowfer smart switch
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3.7 /home/pi/subwoofer_switch/subwoofer_control.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I get the following output after checking the status `sudo systemctl status subwoofer.service` :

```
● subwoofer.service - My script to control suboowfer smart switch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/subwoofer.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-06-07 13:59:34 BST; 5min ago
 Main PID: 6261 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 07 13:59:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started My script to control suboowfer smart switch.
Jun 07 13:59:34 raspberrypi python3[6261]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Jun 07 13:59:34 raspberrypi python3[6261]:   File "/home/pi/subwoofer_switch/subwoofer_control.py", line 1, in <module>
Jun 07 13:59:34 raspberrypi python3[6261]:     import cec
Jun 07 13:59:34 raspberrypi python3[6261]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cec'
Jun 07 13:59:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: subwoofer.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 07 13:59:34 raspberrypi systemd[1]: subwoofer.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I did check that cec library is installed `python3 -m pip install cec`:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Requirement already satisfied: cec in /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.2.7)
```

I don't quite understand what's going wrong.

Comment: The location `/home/pi` is your user account. A system service needs to run on a system account, and from there, won't (and should not, for security reasons) have access to resources controlled by individual users. Trivially, install `cec` from a system account.

Comment: @tripleee thank you, that fixed my problem. Is there a way to change your comment into an answer?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a duplicate anyway.